# How to get number of submission of last 24 hours using Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, api, hibernate, criteria

Can somebody tell me how to find out how many forms were submitted in 24 hours?

I have the submitted time in my database.

[image]

In the dashboard, I need to print the number of submissions for the last 24 hours.

My code

```
@Override
public long last24Hours() {
    Date yesterday = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L);
    CriteriaBuilder cb = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<FormSubmission> formSubmission = query.from(FormSubmission.class);
    query.select(cb.count(formSubmission));
    query.where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(formSubmission.get("submitted"), yesterday));
    Query<Long> q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
    return q.getFirstResult();

    
}
```

But it returning 0, don't know why

Comment: I would turn SQL logging on to see the actual query that's being run, and try that directly in your SQL tool of choice so you can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//this is working

```
@Override
public long last24Hours() {
    Date yesterday = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L);
    CriteriaBuilder cb = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<FlowSubmission> flowSubmission = query.from(FlowSubmission.class);
    query.select(cb.count(flowSubmission));
    query.where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(flowSubmission.get("submitted"), yesterday));
    Query<Long> q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);

    return q.uniqueResult();
}
```